# ApacheDS getting LdapOtherException:null after migrating from version 2.0.0-M20 to 2.0.0-M21

Tags: apache, security, ldap, migration, apacheds

I just upgrade to ApacheDS-2.0.0-M21 due to security vulnerability issues. I've been trying to find any migration guide/considerations but not success so far. After migrating I started getting the folowing error:

```
******* Showing relevant part only ******  org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.exception.LdapOtherException:null
org.apache.directory.server.core.partition.impl.btree.jdbm.JdbmTable#get|JdbmTable.java:371
org.apache.directory.server.core.partition.impl.btree.jdbm.JdbmIndex#forwardLookup|JdbmIndex.java:360
org.apache.directory.server.core.partition.impl.btree.jdbm.JdbmIndex#forwardLookup|JdbmIndex.java:58
org.apache.directory.server.core.partition.impl.btree.AbstractBTreePartition#getEntryId|AbstractBTreePartition.java:2518
org.apache.directory.server.core.partition.impl.btree.AbstractBTreePartition#add|AbstractBTreePartition.java:684
org.apache.directory.server.core.DefaultDirectoryService#initializeSystemPartition|DefaultDirectoryService.java:1755
org.apache.directory.server.core.DefaultDirectoryService#initialize|DefaultDirectoryService.java:1815
org.apache.directory.server.core.DefaultDirectoryService#startup|DefaultDirectoryService.java:1250
```

[ApacheDS Jira page](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DIRSERVER/fixforversion/12332287/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:version-summary-panel)
doesn't show any known issue on this regard, but mention a pseudo migration tool "partition-plumber" that could be the solution.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered asking the question on the ApacheDS project mailing list ?
I would think that this would be the first place to reach the people with knowledge of the differences between the milestone releases.

Comment: I did not try the mailing list but,  I created an issue on ApacheDS JIRA site.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DIRSERVER-2115

Answer (score 0):

ApacheDS guys are aware of the issue and are working on a tool/fix. 
It is planed to be solve in version M22 shown in following link:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DIRSERVER-2121